# Use external cache provider for RazorEngine

Tags: razorengine

Currently RazorEngine, caches the template in memory.
Is there anyway to use an external caching provider?

We have 10 web servers in a webfarm, and now each of them needs to cache the template separately. That would be great if we can implement our own caching system and use something like Memcached.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should now be able to do that in 3.5.0 (currently beta). You can provide your own `ICachingProvider` implementation that fits your needs. Documentation and an example implementation can be found [here](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/Caching.html). What you want to do is saving the compiled assemblies and then loading the assemblies and the template-types when needed.

Disclaimer: I contributed that API to RazorEngine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am so excited that now I can provide my own CachingProvider. However, when I am trying to implement MemcachedCachingProvider to cache the template, it complains since RazorEngine.Templating.CompiledTemplate is not Serializable.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at my comments from https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/278.